# AngularJS not displaying template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started learning AngularJS so I created two html pages:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TodoApp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
        <title>Angular Tutorial</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
               <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

and list.html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test">
<h1>Hello: {{test}}</h1>
```

The app.js looks like this

```
var TodoApp = angular.module("TodoApp", ["ngResource"]).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { controller: ListCtrl, templateUrl: "list.html" }).
            otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    });


var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location)
{
    $scope.test = "testing";        
};
```

Unfortunately, when I open the index.html page it is blank. What can be the cause of the problem?

Comment: please provide error in console

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module TodoApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProvider
    at http://localhost:65019/Scripts/angular.js:63:12
    at http://localhost:65019/Scripts/angular.js:3997:19
    at getService (http://localhost:65019/Scripts/angular.js:4144:39)..

Comment: You need to add ng-route :-)

Comment: Added the ngRoute to dependencies, it works like a charm now, thank you for the response! :)

Comment: Great happy programming:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you mentioned the error:-

1) Add angular-route.js file in main page.

2) Add 'ngRoute' dependency in angular main app.

Doc:-https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 1):

also you need to mention the controller in your HTML with `ng-controller="ListCtrl"` to initialize it.

And do not declare your controller that way, you must do

```
todoApp.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', function($scope, dep1, dep2) {

  $scope.test = "testing";

}]);
```

Comment: I've been watching the tutorial from 2013., I suppose there are some version differences then :/ Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are missing the controller's definition:

```
TodoApp.controller('ListCtrl', ListCtrl);
```

This should fix your issue

Comment: The controller is defined in the module config, but thank you very much for the response anyway, I found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at yeoman. It will help you to start with angularjs in zero time.

http://yeoman.io/codelab.html